# Deploying orchard to Azure with Kudu - MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "AllRules.ruleset"

Tags: azure, deployment, continuous-integration, orchardcms, kudu

### SHORT VERSION

How do I make `warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "AllRules.ruleset".` stop when I try to deploy orchard to azure with kudu?

### LONG VERSION

I'm trying to deploy an [Orchard](http://www.orchardproject.net/) site to Azure using kudu and git, but I'm hitting a roadblock.

[image]

As you can see, the deployment script is hitting a roadblock. I'm using the default .deployment script that comes with Orchard. You can see the deploy.cmd it calls below:

```
@if "%SCM_TRACE_LEVEL%" NEQ "4" @echo off

:: ----------------------
:: KUDU Deployment Script
:: Version: 0.1.11
:: ----------------------

:: Prerequisites
:: -------------

:: Verify node.js installed
where node 2>nul >nul
IF %ERRORLEVEL% NEQ 0 (
  echo Missing node.js executable, please install node.js, if already installed make sure it can be reached from current environment.
  goto error
)

:: Setup
:: -----

setlocal enabledelayedexpansion

SET ARTIFACTS=%~dp0%..\artifacts

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE=%~dp0%.
)

IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TARGET (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TARGET=%ARTIFACTS%\wwwroot
)

IF NOT DEFINED NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH (
  SET NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest

  IF NOT DEFINED PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH (
    SET PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH=%ARTIFACTS%\manifest
  )
)

IF NOT DEFINED KUDU_SYNC_CMD (
  :: Install kudu sync
  echo Installing Kudu Sync
  call npm install kudusync -g --silent
  IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

  :: Locally just running "kuduSync" would also work
  SET KUDU_SYNC_CMD=%appdata%\npm\kuduSync.cmd
)
IF NOT DEFINED DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  SET DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=%temp%\___deployTemp%random%
  SET CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP=true
)

IF DEFINED CLEAN_LOCAL_DEPLOYMENT_TEMP (
  IF EXIST "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%" rd /s /q "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
  mkdir "%DEPLOYMENT_TEMP%"
)

IF NOT DEFINED MSBUILD_PATH (
  SET MSBUILD_PATH=%WINDIR%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe
)

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
:: Deployment
:: ----------

echo Handling .NET Web Application deployment.

:: 1. Restore NuGet packages
call :ExecuteCmd nuget restore "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\src\Orchard.sln"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 2. Build to the temporary path
call :ExecuteCmd "%MSBUILD_PATH%" "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\Orchard.proj" /t:Precompiled /v:m
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

:: 3. KuduSync
call :ExecuteCmd "%KUDU_SYNC_CMD%" -v 50 -f "%DEPLOYMENT_SOURCE%\build\Precompiled" -t "%DEPLOYMENT_TARGET%" -n "%NEXT_MANIFEST_PATH%" -p "%PREVIOUS_MANIFEST_PATH%" -i ".git;.hg;.deployment;deploy.cmd"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

:: Post deployment stub
IF DEFINED POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION call "%POST_DEPLOYMENT_ACTION%"
IF !ERRORLEVEL! NEQ 0 goto error

goto end

:: Execute command routine that will echo out when error
:ExecuteCmd
setlocal
set _CMD_=%*
call %_CMD_%
if "%ERRORLEVEL%" NEQ "0" echo Failed exitCode=%ERRORLEVEL%, command=%_CMD_%
exit /b %ERRORLEVEL%

:error
endlocal
echo An error has occurred during web site deployment.
call :exitSetErrorLevel
call :exitFromFunction 2>nul

:exitSetErrorLevel
exit /b 1

:exitFromFunction
()

:end
endlocal
echo Finished successfully.
```

The script failed on deployment step 2: Build to the temporary path.

More specifically, it throws this warning:

```
D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\bin\Microsoft.CSharp.CurrentVersion.targets(133,9): warning MSB3884: Could not find rule set file "AllRules.ruleset". [D:\home\site\repository\src\Orchard.Web\Modules\Orchard.AuditTrail\Orchard.AuditTrail.csproj]
```

for every single .csproj in the project (and there are many...), and finally exits with:

```
Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe" "D:\home\site\repository\Orchard.proj" /t:Precompiled /v:m
An error has occurred during web site deployment.
```

I have researched what I could and found the following sources:

1. https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/issues/1694

   - davidebbo mentions an HKEY, but I'm not too sure what to do here.
2. [VS2015 MSB3884 warning: Could not find rule set file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33020507/vs2015-msb3884-warning-could-not-find-rule-set-file)

   - They say here I should find CodeAnalysisRuleSetDirectories in my csproj file and change the version of visual studio. Taking the many csproj files into consideration, this does not sound like a sound solution (pun intended).
3. http://www.it1me.com/it-answers?id=33637211&ttl=VS2015%3A+warning+MSB3884%3A+Could+not+find+rule+set+file

   - I haven't tried this, as a comment mentions it will create a absolute path that will not work when deployed to azure. Any thoughts on this?
4. https://github.com/Microsoft/msbuild/issues/361

   - Here kevinbosman mentiones the HKEY again, like davidebbo did in the other git thread. Again, any idea how to implement this on azure?
5. http://www.muddlingthru.ca/one-strategy-for-continuous-integration-with-orchard-git-and-ms-azure-websites

   - This guide recommends using [this deploy.orchard.cmd file](https://github.com/bigfont/orchard-continuous-integration-demo/blob/master/deploy.orchard.cmd) instead. I can see the 3 build steps have been modified, but I'm not too sure if this will work well. Can anyone confirm if this script is any good?

The question is: Any suggestions on how I solve this problem in a smooth manner without having to modify csproj files?

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem by doing what I didn't want to: I deleted all the instances of `<CodeAnalysisRuleSet>AllRules.ruleset</CodeAnalysisRuleSet>` in all csprojs. This removed the error.

I will not mark this answer correct, as it doesn't answer my question. I'm adding it so others who don't mind a less stellar fix can get on with their lives.

BTW I now get MSB3026, MSB3277, and MSB3101 errors, but that is off topic here.